# PHP: Can the FB API Batch Request be used in this case?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-batch-request

Ive got multiple Facebook Fan pages that I need to query the FB.API for (to get info about each page). I noticed that when the number of fanpages that I need to query the API for becomes large there are significant performance issues.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getFanpages)){
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$row["link"];
    $data = json_decode(get_data($url));
    $pageName = $data->name;
    //....Get other info from $data (e.g. page link)
 }
```

Is it possible to use `Batch Request` for such a task? If so, how would the code for that look vs what I currently have?